# I am not able to create a unreal engine 4 c++ project

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

whenever i create a unreal engine 4 c++ project it throw this error

```
Running E:/program_files/UE_4.24/Engine/Binaries/DotNET/UnrealBuildTool.exe  -projectfiles -project="D:/Game Development/MyProject2/MyProject2.uproject" -game -rocket -progress
Discovering modules, targets and source code for project...
ERROR: Could not find NetFxSDK install dir; this will prevent SwarmInterface from installing.  Install a version of .NET Framework SDK at 4.6.0 or higher.
```

I have installed ue4 4.24 version and visual studio 2019 and game development with c++ is also selected during the installination of visual studio 2019 . i downloaded .NET framework from microsoft website but when i install it says **Your installination will not occur see below for reason why .NET Framework 4.8 or a later update is already installed on this computer.** So what can i do Please Help Me !
**Thanks in Advance**

Comment: *Install a version of .NET Framework SDK at 4.6.0 or higher.* SDK, not just .NET Framework. It can be selected at Visual Studio installer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had the same problem, when I tried downloaded .NET framework from microsoft website it said Your installation is not possible because .NET Framework 4.8 or a later update is already installed.

This fix worked:
https://forums.unrealengine.com/development-discussion/blueprint-visual-scripting/1697074-can-t-package-my-project-netfxsdk

"crioto: Hello! As mentioned in the output, you need to install/update .NET Framework. You can do this by running Microsoft Visual Studio Installer, then click on "Modify" next to installed version of Visual Studio, switch tab to Individual Components and check latest version of .NET SDK.*"

Modifying the VS Installer solved the Issue